# React and environment variables

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently a bit confused about react and env variables. Basically, what I would like to achieve is, to have different files. Something like: enviorment.dev.js, enviorment.prod.js.

I couldn't find the documentation and there seem to be a lot of different  options to choose from.

I guess, I look for something like this: https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be just for react.

Comment: React is just a JavaScript library/framework for defining and rendering views. It doesn't have anything to do with environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, there's a plugin, but that's the sort of place where you would need to configure that.  As Felix said, React doesn't do that:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

webpack.config:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
  VERSION: JSON.stringify("5fa3b9"),
  BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
  TWO: "1+1",
  "typeof window": JSON.stringify("object")
})
```

index.js:

```
if (!PRODUCTION) {
  console.log('Debug info')
}

if (PRODUCTION) {
  console.log('Production log')
}
```